# Role-based authorization mechanism for a GAE app

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authorization, acl

I'm looking for a role-based framework/module/package for an app written in Python (2.7) running on Google App Engine.

With role-based I mean a mechanism that would allow me to check (during a request processing most of the time) whether a certain user is able to perform a specific action.

A couple use cases:

- user A should be able to see and modify own profile, whereas user B should only be able to see user A profile.
- user with an "admin" role should be able to see all registered users, whereas user A and user B should only be able to see users with a public profile (e.g. users with user.public property set to True)
- etc.

I'm imagining something like

```
user_a.is_able_to('read', user_b) # -> True of False
```

or

```
user_a.authorize('update', user_b) # raises an exception if 'not allowed to'
```

So far I've only seen [acl.py](http://code.google.com/p/tipfy/source/browse/tipfy/appengine/acl.py) from tipfy. Looks quite simple and pretty much close to what I'm looking for. I'm wondering whether there's something similar to that acl.py, preferably implemented using NDB.

Comment: [Here][1] is a good implementation suggestion.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448308/role-based-security-with-google-app-engine-and-python

Comment: Yeah, I have a couple ideas on how to implement it myself. I was wondering whether there's somebody/something already implemented. It seems not though (a part from tipfy) so I'll probably DIY.

Answer (score 2):

Web2py contains role based access control which I believe works on GAE. This is documented here:

http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/9

You may be able to fork the auth module and mod it for your purposes. I know people have done this with other parts of web2py such as the DAL.

Answer (score 1):

Turbogears and Web2py frameworks have the role based access control you can integrate one of them on GAE Python version.